# Which design pattern do I have

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have two classes, each of them doing same thing but only differences are, that they both use different logic in some function in the code. Let say:

```
class A
{
    //has same fields, and method
    void GetDataTable()
    {
         //logic here changes up to table of the database and for some fields.
    }
}

class B
{
    //has same fields, and method
    void GetDataTable()
    {
         //logic here changes up to table of the database and for some fields.
    }
}
```

At the end of the day, I would add another same behaving class and `GetDataTable` method with different logic. What kind of design pattern or OO technique I have to apply for more quality code.

Comment: You're probably looking for [**Strategy Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: Just as a side node: Getter methods should in general have another return type than void!

Comment: I have a feeling that *inheritance* is what you're looking for seeing as some functionality is identical between the two types (or so you claim - it's not illustrated by the posted code). You should specifically look at *abstract* classes which allow you to better separate the general (common) definitions from the more specialised ones.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As Styxxy suggest I use strategy pattern like that:

Refactoring code so result are:

-More flexible.
-Can change behavior at runtime
-no code duplication

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Apply a = new Apply(); //I will create if I dont need any logic but be able to get AB's behavior, I will call that class NoApply
        Helper(a);

    }
    static void Helper(AB myobj)
    {
        myobj.CanGetDataTable();
    }
}

abstract class AB
{
    IGetDataTable gtb;

    public virtual void LogicSetter(IGetDataTable dt)
    {
        gtb = dt;
    }

    public void CanGetDataTable()
    {
        this.gtb.GetDataTable();
    }
    public void DoSameThingBothAB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("do same things");
    }
}

class Apply:AB
{
    public Apply()
    {
        base.LogicSetter(new LogicForA());
    }
}

public interface IGetDataTable
{
    void GetDataTable();
}

public class LogicForA:IGetDataTable
{
    public void GetDataTable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("logic for A");
    }
}

public class LogicForB:IGetDataTable
{
    public void GetDataTable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("logic for B");
    }
}

public class LogicforFutured:IGetDataTable
{
    public void GetDataTable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("logic for object created in 2019");
    }
}
```

Comment: Providing the output and some description might be helpful, if you post such an elaborated sample.

Comment: You could inject your dependency more gracefully by having an `IGetDataTable` parameter in `AB`s constructor, and marking `gtb` read-only, although you'd obviously lose the "can change behaviour at runtime" feature (which might be a good thing as it seems a bit dangerous). Also: the `Apply` class seems awfully redundant.

Comment: its not reduntant, what if I need a class in future who does apply different behavior, I will call it DifferentApply class and implement behaviour via base.LogicSetter(new NoLogic())

Comment: I assume you meant "no code duplication" instead of "no code reuse".

Comment: @MichaelRiva, *what if I need a class in future who does apply different behavior?* `var ab = new AB(new LogicForFuture())` - and BOOM, new behaviour right there. If you're not getting paid based on the number of lines of code you pump out, losing that extra class won't be a problem.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy nice catch, I call this a bug, and I change as it virtual ;)

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for the [**Strategy Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

You define an interface with the method that each "logic" class has to implement. Each "logic" class will implement this interface and performs its logic in the implemented method.

```
interface IGetDataTable
{
    void GetDataTable();
}

class A : IGetDataTable
{
    public void GetDataTable() { /* Do logic here for class A */ }
}

class B : IGetDataTable
{
    public void GetDataTable() { /* Do logic here for class B */ }
}
```

You then choose the appropriate class (that implements `IGetDataTable`) for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

No pattern per se, just inheritance.

I've used an abstract class instead of an interface because you mentioned there are common methods.

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    // TODO: Common methods here.

    // Inheriting classes must implement this.
    public abstract void GetDataTable();
}

public class A : MyBaseClass
{
    public void GetDataTable()
    {
        // Specific implementation here.
    }
}

public class B : MyBaseClass
{
    public void GetDataTable()
    {
        // Specific implementation here.
    }
}
```

If you have something that uses these classes - but only the `GetDataTable` method then it would be good practice to have an interface.  `IGetDataTable` for example.

If not, there's no need, the abstract class *is* the interface.

```
public interface IGetDataTable
{
    void GetDataTable();
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass : IGetDataTable
{
    // TODO: Common methods here.

    // Inheriting classes must implement this.
    public abstract void GetDataTable();
}

public class A : MyBaseClass
{
    public void GetDataTable()
    {
        // Specific implementation here.
    }
}

public class B : MyBaseClass
{
    public void GetDataTable()
    {
        // Specific implementation here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Inheritance is a pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), or simply make common abstract ancestor for both of the classes.